# Micro data on parental education

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset that contains data about mother's education and father's education for adults (data just for kids I've found to be not sufficient). I am writing my Thesis about effects of the parental education on an individual's education and how it varies, so I would love to has the data for various low and middle-income countries. Do you know, where can I find it?

P.S. DHS program should contain those variables in older releases(  [manual](http://www.dhsprogram.com/pubs/pdf/DHSG4/Recode6_DHS_22March2013_DHSG4.pdf)  - see page 111), but I found only data for Mother's education there (Household members recode).

Comment: i don't follow the question 100%...or rather, i'm not sure what data you want...you don't want parental education of adults that have kids? i know where some us and international data is regarding parental education....

Comment: I am not concerned about whether the person has kids or not. But I need data for people from all age groups(not just within 0-20 years old). Any data on parental education should be fine. Can you please give me the link ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe all of these microdata sets have education of both parents and children, although some of them are limited to parent-child while they are co-habiting.

international:

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/program%20for%20international%20student%20assessment%20%28pisa%29

has education level of parents, for example `HISCED` on pdf page 244 https://pisa2012.acer.edu.au/downloads/M_stu_codebook.pdf#page=244

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/programme%20for%20the%20international%20assessment%20of%20adult%20competencies%20%28piaac%29

also has it, for example see pdf page 1492,
www.oecd.org/site/piaac/codebook_synthetic.pdf#page=1492

within the united states:

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/current%20population%20survey%20%28cps%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/survey%20of%20income%20and%20program%20participation%20%28sipp%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20study%20of%20adolescent%20to%20adult%20health%20%28addhealth%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20surveys%20%28nls%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/youth%20risk%20behavior%20surveillance%20system%20%28yrbss%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/panel%20study%20of%20income%20dynamics%20%28psid%29

Answer (score 1):

National Center for Education Statistics by DOE has reports with data like this, and I've seen at least one International section header, so there's at least some non-US data there.
http://nces.ed.gov/

PubMed is "a free full-text archive of biomedical and life sciences journal literature at the U.S. National Institutes of Health's National Library of Medicine (NIH/NLM)" and it also has some of this data.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/